# 403 redirect error when submitting form Codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, redirect, http-status-code-403

I get a 403 error when running the form from the first part of [this tutorial](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html).

I contacted my host after researching and suspecting a mod_security limitation, they tell me I'm hitting an internal redirect limit of 10. The error is below. They say they won't support development but I suspect that since I'm using the template files that it's their environment causing the problem.

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://mywebsite.com/automation/codeigniter/form
```

How can I find the cause of the redirect loop, or otherwise fix my 403 error?

Edit: the URL from the tutorial has me going to `http://mywebsite.com/includes/codeigniter/index.php/form`

The form...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open(base_url('controllers/form.php')); ?>

<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Password</h5>
<input type="text" name="password" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Password Confirm</h5>
<input type="text" name="passconf" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Email Address</h5>
<input type="text" name="email" value="" size="50" />

<br><br>

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

</form>

<?php echo form_close() ?>

</body>
</html>
```

The controller...

```
    <?php

class Form extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('myform');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Note CodeIgniter user a [Front Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that .htaccess of root of Codeigniter dir does not restrict http POST i.e.

deny from all

If there is no .htaccess, check in parent dir's where this limit might be inherited, since htaccess rules are applied recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at your rewrite rules - that's often a case of redirection trouble.

Check the CI routing configuration - a bit strange: "index.php/form"

You might set the CI `LogLevel` to `debug` to get the backtrace.

Comment: /form is how Codeigniter works. I know, it's a little weird and the first time I have come across this. Do you mean htaccess rewrite rules? I have checked them. I can supply my htaccess, which dir should I retrieve it from?

Comment: Just disable them for a moment, to test, if they do not clash with the CI routes.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo form_open(); ?>
```

Instead of putting 'form' this should be the URL to the controller that will process the form.
Since you did not post your controller I can't really tell you what to put there.

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url('controller/method/arguments')); ?>
```

Also if you are going to use the form helper.. might as well close the form with it as well.

```
<?php echo form_close() ?>
```

Use htaccess in the root to remove index.php from the url.. something like this would work..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: OK I made those changes, which htaccess do I update? User root, domain or addon domain?

Comment: I changed both and it didn't work. Also I don't quite understand why I need to change `<?php echo form_open(); ?>` as the tutorial doesn't require this.

Comment: Have you got this code working on your local dev environment? or are you testing this on the hosted server? You should be testing this locally before pushing it to your host. The htaccess file goes into the root of your project.. this will remove the index.php from the url. Now that I see your controller it should be like this after you fix the htaccsess. <?php echo form_open(base_url('form/index')); ?>  or just form like you had it should also work since it will default to the index of the controller.

Comment: Agree about the test environment. Although this specific site is a one off (fundraising). I don't have a huge reason to set one up... diminishing returns et al. Maybe this is the incentive I need though. What is the root of the project specifically? The codeigniter dir, application dir or the controller dir? Also... if /form should just work, why bother mentioning it/diverting from the tutorial? Thanks for your help though.

Comment: I think I found it, the dir `includes` has a htaccess with the following `<Limit POST PUT>
  deny from all
  allow from 127.0.0.1
</Limit>
Options -Indexes` when I removed that file the error stopped. I'd like to leave it there, so what should I add in the `Codeigniter` dir to recursively override the relevant parent dir's htaccess settings?